# android scroll and swipe difficulty

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, scroll, swipe

Good Evening,
i am having a problem with android 4.1 when it comes to scrolling and swiping. (I am using jquery mobile)

I have a list which you can delete items from by simply swiping to the right. When it comes to iOS, everything is really crisp. But it seems that android cant handle scrolling and swiping on the same element. You can only scroll in a 90° angle, but changing it to ~85° messes up the scrolling.

When i remove the swiping event, everything works fine. Is there a known fix for that?

Regards Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold is the answer to that problem.

JqueryMobiel supresses scrolling when there is a swipe event on an item. Simply modify the values above to your liking and you'll be fine!

```
$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = "30px";
```

30px is not the right parameter, it is 30 (without px), but 30px solves my problem.